# check Product procurement category hierarchy

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I m working with `dynamics ax 2012` and i m looking for a fonction that  verifie if a product is exist in the `procurement category hierarchy`
This listepage `Product Information Management -> Common -> Products -> Released Product`  show  list of product released
in the `actionpane product` ,we have button  validate ; when i select a record in the `grid control` and clicked in the button validate

i should verifie if the  procurement category is attached to this product , there is no error ;if no procurement category is attached to this product ,it must display an arror  message

Apparently , the procurement category is a category hierarchy which I will go look for if the product is attached for this category,
How can i create a fonction to search in the category hierarchy

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two tables to do that validation:

1. Table `EcoResProductCategory` tells who what categories and category hierarchies a product has.
2. Table `EcoResCategoryHierarchyRole` tells you what role a category hierarchy has. The role itself is the enum `EcoResCategorynamedHierarchyRole` and there you can find the element `Procurement`.

Now you can combine these two tables in a query that checks if the product has a category in a category hierarchy that has the Procurement role.

Comment: Thank you i have solved the broblem  by following of step you montioned

Answer (score 0):

In the  class `EcoResProductValidatonService`  this class  is called by the button  validate in th This listepage **Product Information Management -> Common -> Products -> Released Product** : I m traying  this code , what do you think ?    is there another why to do that?

```
EcoResProductCategory               resProductCateg;
         if (TableParm::find().ProcRescatgProduct){

                InventTable = InventTable::find( 'Item id' ); // pass the item id
                resProductCateg = EcoResProductCategory::findByProductIdCategoryHierarchyRole(inventTable.Product,EcoResCategoryNamedHierarchyRole::Procurement);
                if(resProductCateg){
                   info(strFmt(" %1   procurement category is attached to this product ",InventTable.ItemId));

                }else{
                     info(strFmt(" %1 No procurement category is attached to this product ",InventTable.ItemId));
                  }
            }
```

The problem  is the value of resProductCateg is alywas 0  knowing that  i have  the product in procurment category